Runtime error in Angular 13 while importing AngularFireAuthModule import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
I'm getting errors in terminal while running build

Error: node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/dist/auth-compat/index.d.ts:53:421 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
53 import { type User, type Unsubscribe, type ActionCodeInfo, type UserCredential, type Auth, type IdTokenResult, type MultiFactorError, type MultiFactorResolver, type PopupRedirectResolver, type Dependencies, type AuthCredential, type ApplicationVerifier, type ConfirmationResult, type AuthProvider, type MultiFactorUser, type NextOrObserver, type ErrorFn, type CompleteFn, type ActionCodeSettings, type Persistence, type PhoneAuthCredential } from "@firebase/auth";

I think there is some issue with version compatability issues with **Angular 13 .**I tried multiple versions of angular/fire but no one worked.
package.json:
"dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "@firebase/auth": "^1.7.2",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.8.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },

I'm not getting error in app module file while importing. I only get error when i run code:
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire/compat'
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
@NgModule({

  imports: [

    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), 
    AngularFireAuthModule
    
  ],

